# Pulling new Unsubscribes into an existing DE - results in duplicate key error

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automation

Trying to create an automation that finds all new unsubscribes and adds them to a data extension.  Writing the **Query** to pull all the records via an **Overwrite** works great, but we need to ensure we are adding new names and no one drops off after the **_Unsubscribe** table data retention window expires (6 months)

I've used this type of query in the past without issue, but today it's just not working and I'm completely stumped.

```
SELECT 
d.SubscriberKey,
d.AccountID,
d.EventDate 
from _Unsubscribe d
LEFT JOIN unsubscribes u ON d.SubscriberKey = u.SubscriberKey 
WHERE u.SubscriberKey IS NULL
```

The query is set to **UPDATE** ... what am I missing here?

Comment: What is your primary key on the Data Extension?

Comment: The Primary Key is SubscriberKey

Comment: That is likely the issue - subscribers can unsubscribe to multiple lists / publications, and sometimes even a single unsubscribe is duplicated in the Unsubscribe data view. Try to set the EventDate as other part of primary key, or specify a specific list ID/Name in your query.

Comment: Could you please try SELECT 
DISTINCT d.SubscriberKey,
d.AccountID,
d.EventDate 
from _Unsubscribe d
LEFT JOIN unsubscribes u ON d.SubscriberKey = u.SubscriberKey 
WHERE u.SubscriberKey IS NULL

Comment: i have added distinct to the SQL which means you won't get the duplicates while selecting from the query

Comment: @BradSapkota - I did as suggested, but still receive the same error.

Comment: @AnonWonderer - If I add the date/time stamp to the query then my results will not provide a unique count of those who unsubscribed.  I suppose I could then write to a new DE and pull only uniques, but I know I've had this working before!

Comment: @AnonWonderer Can you please share the screenshot of the DE attributes?

Comment: I assume the screenshot ask is for me...

[IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/214r4te.png[/IMG]

Comment: That's what I am saying - you're looking for unique subscribers, but you're referencing a data view that tracks unsubscribes across all your lists / publication lists - which can contain multiple records per subscriber. If you only want the status as held on the All Subscribers list, you can specify that in your query OR reference the _Subscriber data view and pull in WHERE status = unsubscribed.